# Loading files in a for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to load different file names contained in a matlab vector inside a for loop. I wrote the following:

```
fileNames = ['fileName1.mat', ..., 'fileName_n.mat'];
for i=1:n
    load(fileNames(i))
    ...
end
```

However, it doesn't work because `fileNames(i)` returns the first letter of the filename only.

How can I give the full file name as argument to load (the size of the string of the filename can vary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cell instead of an array.

```
fileNames = {'fileName1.mat', ..., 'fileName_n.mat'};
```

Your code is in principle a string cat, giving you just one string (since strings are arrays of characters).

```
for i=1:n
    load(fileNames{i})
    ...
end
```

Use `{` and `}` instead of parentheses.